# How can we find the optimum K value in K-Nearest Neighbor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am learning Ml from udemy and below is the code that instructor  use in his lecture.But I am not totally satisfied with this code because it gives many k value whose eror_rate are almost same(I have to manually check k value whose error rate are negligible).

Is there any other method available to find the best k value (`n_neighbor`)?

```
error_rate = []
for i in range(1,40):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred_i = knn.predict(X_test)
    error_rate.append(np.mean(pred_i != y_test))
```

using plot to show Error rate vs K value.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(range(1,40),error_rate,color='blue', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
markerfacecolor='red', markersize=10)
plt.title('Error Rate vs. K Value')
plt.xlabel('K')
plt.ylabel('Error Rate')
```

[image: Error rate vs k_value fig]

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Answer (score 5):

GridSearchCV and other similar algorithms are available in sklearn which can be used to do cross-validation and find optimal parameter

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

k_range = list(range(1,100))
weight_options = ["uniform", "distance"]

param_grid = dict(n_neighbors = k_range, weights = weight_options)


knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

grid = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid, cv = 10, scoring = 'accuracy')
grid.fit(X,y)

print (grid.best_score_)
print (grid.best_params_)
print (grid.best_estimator_)


# 0.9800000000000001
# {'n_neighbors': 13, 'weights': 'uniform'}
# KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
#                     metric_params=None, n_jobs=None, n_neighbors=13, p=2,
#                     weights='uniform')
```

All algorithms are available here. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#hyper-parameter-optimizers